# dbms_output size buffer overflow

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, sqlplus, dbms-output

I tried to set the `dbms_output` size to unlimited inside a stored procedure.

But it gave me compilation errors.  So I tried in the SQL*Plus prompt the below way. But still I get the buffer overflow error.  How can I overcome this?

```
 set serveroutput on size unlimited;
 exec service_update;


ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 30000 bytes
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 32
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 97
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT", line 112
ORA-06512: at "ARBOR.SERVICE_UPDATE", line 27
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the procedure service_update, by any chance is there a call to

```
dbms_output.enable(30000);
```

This may override the first limit you set.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  set the size to unlimited dbms_output.enable(null) and it worked

Answer (score 7):

In Oracle 10gR2 you may also use unlimited buffer (https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=361639):

```
dbms_output.enable(null);
```