# ORA-20000: ORU 10027: Buffer overflow,limit of 20000 bytes

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure

We have an oracle SP where it is using many dbms output to print the result set. Due to this the procedure is only executed partially and throws error message ORA-20000: ORU 10027: Buffer overflow,limit of 20000 bytes.
Tried to declare below in Sp
Set serveroutput on size 1000000
But it is not compiled and showing the error "Encountered the symbol ON when expecting one of the following:   := .(@%; not null range default characte

Please provide suggestion of how to increase the buffer size

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971862/procedure-buffer-overflow

Comment: `set serveroutput` is a client command (SQL\*Plus etc.), not SQL or PL/SQL. You probably want to use that, or the client equivalent; there is an [`enable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_OUTPUT.html#GUID-C742297F-A8DC-4E62-A18D-76DDF2638356) call that takes a buffer size, but it's usually done from the client.